# How to store an unbalanced tree in a matrix

Tags: data-structures, matrix, tree, graph-algorithm

I am working with a vocabulary tree, a `k-ary` tree data structure with depth `L`, which is the result of iteratively running hierarchical `k-means` clustering. It is an unbalanced structure since the clustering process might stop when the number of assigned data points to a cluster is smaller than the number of clusters.

My problem is that I am requiring to store this tree in a matrix format.

I thought about simply storing it in breadth-first order but the memory waste might be too high if the difference between the actual number of nodes, let's say `n`, and the theoretical number of nodes in a balanced tree increases, that is:

```
n << (1-k^L)/(1-k)
```

Is there any way of efficiently storing an unbalanced tree in a matrix form without wasting memory or wasting the less possible?

Answer (score -2):

It seems like it would be rather difficult not to waste any space. However, the a fairly simple approach is outlined below and requires only O(N log_k N) space or O(k N log_k N) if the space for the leafs are always allocated (useful in some cases), where N is the number of elements in the tree. The cost is that accessing an element requires O(log_k N).

The exact implementation is rather variable as it depends on a number of factors. The idea is to simply generalize the representation of a balanced binary tree as an array, to work as an unbalanced n-ary tree as a matrix. This is done by having the matrix cells act as nodes. The information contained in a node could be either located in a single cell with a data structure, or spread out over the next few cells. The main thing is that each node must contain information for that specific node as well as information as to the location of any children it has. An incremental pointer is then used to track where the next free spot for children is located.

Overall, it's just an array with less than or equal to r*c elements, that has been broken up into a matrix of r rows and c columns. A list of lists might be more useful as row L would contain the nodes at depth L. Otherwise, there isn't much useful there.